# how can i fix this invalid ELF header errror?

Tags: linux

I installed zeromq on ubuntu 10.04 and the compilation went through without any errors.

However when i try to run the python test, it results in this error:

```
jerome@VM1:~/zeromq/pyzmq-2.0.7$ python setup.py test
running test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 144, in <module>
    'Topic :: System :: Networking'
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/distutils/dist.py", line 975, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/distutils/dist.py", line 995, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "setup.py", line 59, in run
    tests = TestLoader().loadTestsFromNames(testfiles)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/unittest.py", line 613, in loadTestsFromNames
    suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/unittest.py", line 576, in loadTestsFromName
    module = __import__('.'.join(parts_copy))
  File "/home/jerome/zeromq/pyzmq-2.0.7/zmq/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from zmq import _zmq
ImportError: /home/jerome/zeromq/pyzmq-2.0.7/zmq/_zmq.so: invalid ELF header
```

What do i need to do to fix this?

Comment: `file /home/jerome/zeromq/pyzmq-2.0.7/zmq/_zmq.so` and `uname -a`

Comment: /home/jerome/zeromq/pyzmq-2.0.7/zmq/_zmq.so: Mach-O bundle i386

Comment: Linux VM1 2.6.32-24-generic #39-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 28 06:07:29 UTC 2010 i686 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting up pyzmq like this:

```
python setup.py configure --zmq=<your_zmqlibrary_installation_path>
python setup.py build_ext --rpath=<your_zmqlibrary_installation_path>/lib --inplace
python setup.py install
python setup.py test
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [how can i fix this invalid ELF header errror?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3668059/how-can-i-fix-this-invalid-elf-header-errror#comment3862222_3668059) you need to compile *zeromq* on your target instead of using a MAC OS X version ...